# Moving faster in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My Question is how can I move my character faster if a certain button is pressed? I tried it with `stepSimulation()` from `btDynamicsWorld`. Also did I set different values but the only result was that the fps dropped dramatically. So which methods can u use to control the movement of the character? I just try to get into android games development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow some basic LibGDX tutorials. In any tutorial where you can move a character, find out where the character's x and y coordinates are being set on input. When the "certain button" is pressed, just change the multiplier that affects movement.

For example, in the [official tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game) they have this code in the `render` method:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()
```

Here the multiplier is 200. Change the multiplier and the speed will change.

(If you're just getting started, you should follow some *simple* tutorials step-by-step, and preferably on desktop because it's easier to work.)

Comment: yeah thanks, that actually helps me. And also thanks for the link, i know i need a lot to learn.

Comment: No worries, @member2. I'm just learning too actually. I'm working out of a book, but these online courses by Udacity/Amazon look really good: [2D Game Development with libGDX](https://www.udacity.com/course/2d-game-development-with-libgdx--ud405) and the follow-up [How to Make a Platformer Using libGDX](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-make-a-platformer-using-libgdx--ud406) -- they're both free.